# C#: Selenium getting ::before pseudo selector data

Tags: c#, css, selenium, css-selectors

I'm having some trouble receiving pseudo selector data.

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(selector));`

My selector string is essentially `button:nth-child(2)` which works fine,
but I also need to get the pseudo data as well and `button:nth-child(2)::before`
isn't quite working, it just remains null.

Is my syntax incorrect or should I be using a different method or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Selenium API doesn't support pseudo elements, but you can get the properties of the current style with a piece of JavaScript:

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(...));

var pseudo_content = driver.ExecuteScript(
    "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],':before').getPropertyValue('content');"
    , elem);
```