# I cant Locate the Xpath of Pseudo Comment

Tags: c#, selenium

I just want to know how to get the Xpath Of pseudo Element Actually the thing is that in This I want to .CLick() on this Div Its role Is button so i tried just To xpath with Div Class name it is locating the element but Not clicking i have to Click On this ::after But i cant Get the Xpath Because it is a Pseudo Element

```
<div id=":l6" class="T-I J-J5-Ji amD T-I-awG T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-Gs L3" 
              role="button" tabindex="0" 
              data-tooltip="Older" 
              aria-label="Older" 
              style="user-select: none;" 
              xpath="1">

  <span class="amF" 
        aria-hidden="true">
     &nbsp;
  </span>
  <img class="amJ T-I-J3" 
       src="images/cleardot.gif" alt="">
::after
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the full HTML at least a few elements above?

Comment: can you please tell me How to add screenshot so i can explain you well

Comment: Just copy past the DOM... or provide the url...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rw7Hh3sUtnmM110OFV0kkhB2HdS_gllM

Comment: this is like a button ::after But i cant get the XPath of this

Comment: Please take a minute to add capitalization, punctuation, etc. to your question. Right now it looks like a ransom note and is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

What I have read ["The Selenium API doesn't support pseudo-elements"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444768/8179099).

So you can use try using `Actions`.

I have a sample (I don't have the full path you can add) here with CssSelector:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Session.Driver);
action.MoveToElement(FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.img::after"))).ContextClick().Build().Perform();
```

As a last resort, you can use JavaScript with `ExecuteScript` something like this:

```
var afterElem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.img"));

var buttonAfter = driver.ExecuteScript(
    "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],'::after');"
    , afterElem);
buttonAfter.click();
```

You will need to play with the CssSelector Or use an XPath.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: unknown error: window.getComputedStyle(...).click is not a function\n  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Comment: Now This Is the Error After Executing Script

Comment: You are right! My bad! I fixed it should work now... I didn't check it but this answer should give you an idea on how to click it...

Comment: Nooo Broo I still Can't Understand How to click On a Pseudo Element

Comment: As I pointed out in the answer the best way is to use `Actions`, I don't have the HTML or a link to the site so I don't know how I can help you more than just recommending what to do without working code...